# React this.state undefined when submitting form

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build a simple form using .net core 3.1 + ReactJS but for some reason this.state is empty when calling the `handleSave(event)`.

**This is my form code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Quote extends Component {
    static displayName = Quote.name;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            name: "",
            firstName: "",
            email: "",
            phone: "",
            budget: "",
            message: ""
        };

        this.handleName = this.handleName.bind(this);
        this.handleFirstName = this.handleFirstName.bind(this);
        this.handleEmail = this.handleEmail.bind(this);
        this.handlePhone = this.handlePhone.bind(this);
        this.handleBudget = this.handleBudget.bind(this);
        this.handleMessage = this.handleMessage.bind(this);
    }

    handleName(event) {
        this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
    }

    handleFirstName(event) {
        this.setState({ firstName: event.target.value });
    }

    handleEmail(event) {
        this.setState({ email: event.target.value });
    }

    handlePhone(event) {
        this.setState({ phone: event.target.value });
    }

    handleBudget(event) {
        this.setState({ budget: event.target.value });
    }

    handleMessage(event) {
        this.setState({ message: event.target.value });
    }

    handleSave(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const data = new FormData();
        data.append("name", this.state.name);
        data.append("firstName", this.state.firstName);
        data.append("email", this.state.email);
        data.append("phone", this.state.phone);
        data.append("budget", this.state.budget);
        data.append("message", this.state.message);

        console.log(data);

        fetch("Quote/Contact", {
            method: "POST",
            body: data
        }).then(response => response.json());
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <body>
               <form onSubmit={this.handleSave}>
                    <div class="service-form">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 mb10 ">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 ">
                                <div class="form-group service-form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label sr-only" for="name"></label>
                                    <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Prénom" value={this.state.firstName} onChange={this.handleFirstName} class="form-control" required/>
                                    <div class="form-icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12  ">
                                    <div class="form-group service-form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label sr-only" for="name"></label>
                                    <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Nom de famille" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleName}  class="form-control" required/>
                                        <div class="form-icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
                                        </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 ">
                                    <div class="form-group service-form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label sr-only" for="email"></label>
                                    <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleEmail}  class="form-control" required/>
                                        <div class="form-icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 ">
                                        <div class="form-group service-form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label sr-only" for="phone"></label>
                                    <input id="phone" type="text" placeholder="Téléphone" value={this.state.phone} onChange={this.handlePhone}  class="form-control" required/>
                                            <div class="form-icon"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></div>
                                        </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 ">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label sr-only" for="select"></label>
                                    <div class="select">
                                        <select id="select" name="select" value={this.state.budget} onChange={this.handleBudget} class="form-control">
                                            <option value="">Budget</option>
                                            <option value="">&lt; 150€</option>
                                            <option value="">150€ - 500€</option>
                                            <option value="">&gt; 500€</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 ">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label sr-only" for="textarea"></label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" name="textarea" value={this.state.message} onChange={this.handleMessage} rows="3" placeholder="Messages"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 ">
                                <button type="submit" value="Submit" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mb10">Envoyer</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </body>
         );
    }
}
```

I'm being greated with :

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')
handleSave
D:/Dev/Web/MCIT/MCIT/ClientApp/src/components/Quote.js:54
  51 |        event.preventDefault();
  52 | 
  53 |        const data = new FormData();
> 54 |        data.append("name", this.state.name);
     | ^  55 |        data.append("firstName", this.state.firstName);
  56 |        data.append("email", this.state.email);
  57 |        data.append("phone", this.state.phone);
```

Comment: Looks like a typo. You forgot to bind `handleSave`. Also note that the state is not empty, it is undefined -> not present at all. If it were empty, then you wouldn't get this error but simply appending an empty value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to bind this function in your constructor, that's why `this` is undefined in `handleSave` handler:

```
this.handleSave = this.handleSave.bind(this);
```

Comment: Oh my god, this is so stupid, and I spent so many time on this. Thank you !